# Real time ant build analyzer

Tags: ant, build

Is there any Ant tool to Analyze Ant build activities during run time? Due to lack of time i don;t want to go through each line of code in the ant script to understand what it is doing. It would be great if i can get any suggestions for anysuch tools.

Comment: Be more specific in what you mean by a build analyser. What sort of output are you looking for? Your questions sounds like you don't want to read the build file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ANT documentation on ANT [loggers and listeners](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html).

To print everything that ANT is doing I'd suggest using the very powerful log4j listener.

## Example

The log4j listener needs some setup. Example can be run as follows:

```
ant bootstrap
ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener -lib .
```

It generates a log file with detailing each step within the build:

```
[     0]  Project : Build started.
[    94]   Target : Target "run1" started.
[   319]     Echo : Run1: Hello world
[   320]   Target : Target "run1" finished.
[   320]   Target : Target "run2" started.
[   321]     Echo : Run2: Hello world
[   321]   Target : Target "run2" finished.
[   321]   Target : Target "run" started.
[   321]   Target : Target "run" finished.
[   328]  Project : Build finished.
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="ANT listener" default="run">

  <target name="bootstrap">
    <get src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar" dest="log4j.jar"/>

    <echo file="log4j.properties">
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, LogFile
log4j.logger.org.apache.tools.ant.Project=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.tools.ant.Target=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Echo=WARN

log4j.appender.LogFile=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%6r] %8c{1} : %m%n
log4j.appender.LogFile.file=build.log
    </echo>
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="run1,run2">
  </target>

  <target name="run1">
    <echo message="Run1: Hello world"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run2">
    <echo message="Run2: Hello world"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Mark Thankyou very much for the info. What i am looking for is, a tool which can heighlight all the activity what a ant build script is doing during the build. No matter if it shows the results in a plain text or  somekind of map.I will try the above steps that you mentioned.