# Separate Stderr and stdout stream at CLI using log4j configuration

Tags: ant, log4j

I have an ANT based application and I have used slf4j logger to log at the exception, info, fatal etc. It is working fine. I am using log4j configuration for logging details. I used slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar for this.  Below is the configuration for logs.

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, file, stdout, stderr
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=cmd.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n

log4j.appender.errorFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorFile.File=error_stream.log
log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.errorFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.errorFile.Threshold=ERROR

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p - %m%n
```

I am calling my application through ant script as ant -f build.xml 1>out.txt 2>err.txt 
Now it should stream all errors to err.txt. But its going into out.txt

Note : it is able to create error_stream.log and have errors. But not in err.txt

Do I am using wrong configuration properties?

Comment: Removed log4j2 tag since this is a log4j1 question. (Consider migrating because log4j 1.2 is broken in Java 9: https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/moving_on_to_log4j_2 )

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to define logging for your application launched by ANT? Or are you trying to define logging for ANT (the process encapsulating your application)?

If it's the latter, then ANT supports [loggers and listeners](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html), for an example:

- [Real time ant build analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055760/real-time-ant-build-analyzer/12061610#12061610)

Comment: I defined loggers in Custom ANT task and logging there. I used above mention log4j configuration to get log.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with ant Task class. It handleErrorOutput as "warning" and further warning is stream into output stream.

You can modify the ant.jar with below changes. It will work.

**Task_before_changes.java**

```
    protected void handleErrorOutput(String output) {
    log(output, Project.MSG_WARN);
}
```

**Task_after_changes.java**

```
protected void handleErrorOutput(String output) {
    log(output, Project.MSG_ERR);
}
```

---